# Tracking missing records between migrated tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table called TABLE1 as follow

```
ID   | SP_NUMBER |CATEGORY
------------------------
1        101         A
2        101         B
3        101         C
4        102         A
5        102         B
6        103         A
7        103         C
```

suppose I migrated above table data to new table called TABLE2

```
ID   | SP_NUMBER |CATEGORY
------------------------
1        101         A
2        101         C
3        102         A
4        102         B
5        103         C
```

Note that , after the migration TABLE2 missing some records. I want genarelise way to track those missing data

as a example I need to show

```
101         B
103         A
```

are not migrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MINUS`

```
select sp_number,category FROM TABLE1 MINUS 
SELECT sp_number,category from TABLE2;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c8c7/2)